# Does AWS Elastic Beanstalk support OpenEJB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy an application which uses EJB architecture. Does AWS Elastic Beanstalk support OpenEJB or maybe there is a way to add it to the Tomcat instance under AWS Elastic Beanstalk? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does AWS Elastic Beanstalk support OpenEJB?

Presumably not, insofar the Tomcat configuration is fairly standard (though I don't know for sure, you may just try yourself of course).

> Is [there] a way to add it to the Tomcat instance under AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Certainly - The possibility to customize your environments is indeed one of the key characteristics of [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) in comparison to other PaaS offerings:

> Most existing application containers or platform-as-a-service
>   solutions, while reducing the amount of programming required,
>   significantly diminish developers' flexibility and control. [...] However, with Elastic
>   Beanstalk, you retain full control over the AWS resources powering
>   your application. If you decide you want to take over some (or all) of
>   the elements of their infrastructure, you can do so seamlessly [...]

What you are looking for is possible by facilitating a *Custom AMI*. Once you have launched an environment, you can customize its configuration details, amongst those the AMI used by your instances as illustrated in [Configuring Servers](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html). While there are some requirements to be  met in order to properly execute within Beanstalk, you can basically customize these AMIs to your heart's content, the process is documented in [Using Custom AMIs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customami.html) (for a 3rd party explanation see e.g. [How to customize an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instance](http://blog.jetztgrad.net/2011/02/how-to-customize-an-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-instance/)).

Please see my respective answer to the related question [Instance's deployment / post configuration for AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://serverfault.com/a/350915/10305) for an important implication to be aware off for customized AMIs.

Good luck!